# Wiener Filtering: Mean Square Error Problems

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I am attempting to write a code to deconvolve an Instrument Response function, IRF (also known as a Point Spread Function, PSF), from an image, convolved with this unknown function, using the original 'true' image. The original and the convoluted image are both greyscale images which have been centred and scaled appropriately. The true image does not have noise but the other does which has lead me to Wiener filtering to try and remove noise whilst acquiring the IRF.

The Parameters are as such:

`t`: true image

`c`: convoluted image

```
T=fft2(t);
C=fft2(C);
```

`K` is scalar value, which is the noise-to-signal ratio (or 1/signal-to-noise, whichever way suits)

The formula I have found for deconvolution using this filter is:

```
L=conj(T)./(T*conj(T)+K)
IRF=L.*C
```

What I am attempting to do is estimate the signal-to-noise ratio (which is unknown) in order to find an ideal K by computing the forumla above and then calculating the mean square error for various values of `K` between `0.001` and `0.1`. I have the following code:

```
K=linspace(0.001,0.1,100);
for i=1:length(K);
    L=conj(T)./(T*conj(T)+K(i));
    IRF=L.*C;
    Cv=uint8(ifft2(C));
    %Mean Square Error is Here:
    e=uint8(t)-Cv;      
    Ev(i)=mean(e(:))^2;
end

[minErrorValue minErrorPos]=min(Ev);
idealK=K(minErrorPos);
L=conj(T)./(T*conj(T)+idealK);
IRF=L.*C;
IRFfinal=ifft2(IRF);
```

I found the code for the mean square error online but I believe its wrong cause all I'm getting is a vector whose entries are all the same value. Plus I'm getting absolute nonsense in my final image which leads me to believe that the noise is still present within the data. I thought how it should be calculated would lead to a mean square error for each individual `K(i)`. Is there another way to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In wiener deconvolution `L=conj(H)./(H*conj(H)+K);`, `H = fft2(IRF)` is the instrument response. And the deconvolution is used to estimate the 'true' image given the blurred image and PSF. I don't think you can use the formula to estimate the `IRF`;
2. All your `Ev` elements in your code are constant because they are just the difference between your true image and convoluted image. Trying to find out `K` doesn't make much sense, because what you need to compare is the estimated IRF and true IRF, and the latter is just unknown.

---

There are two possible methods to determine the blurred kernel.

**The 1st one** is to optimize the objective function:

`min(sum([c(x,y)-IRF(x,y)*t(x,y)]^2) + lambda*sum(IRF(x,y)^2));` for each pixel `(x,y)`, where regularization term is to constrain the norm of the blurred kernel.

You have:

```
gradient_pixel(x,y) = -[c(x,y) - IRF(x,y)*t(x,y)]*t(x,y) + lambda*IRF(x,y);
IRF(x,y) = IRF(x,y) - eta * gradient_pixel(x,y);
```

Iteratively estimate the `IRF`.

**The 2nd method** is to use the cross correlation, suppose the size of `IRF` is `sIRF`:

```
t1 = im2col(t, sIRF, 'sliding')';
IRF1 = t1 \ c(:);
IRF = rot90(reshape(IRF1, sIRF), 2);
```

This is pretty easy.

Comment: This is theoretical stuff Im doing as part of a thesis. I have used a no noise Wiener filter (Inverse filter) to compute an IRF out of a convoluted image without noise with the original image. In ur code what does the Lambda and eta stand for? Is the Blur Kernel just the PSF? Sorry I'm still new to Matlab and this style of mathematics.

Comment: Is there also an external reference which would be helpful for this kind of thing? I searched blur kernel estimation but came up with nothing

Comment: lambda is a regularization factor usually less than 1:0.1,0.01,..., eta is the update rate, usually using 0.5. And yes the blurred kernel is PSF.  Maybe you can try method 2 which is equivalent to directly applying C./T but for many small blocks, the size of each block is the same as the size of blur kernel, so the problem converts to a over-determined matrix equation

Comment: one reference paper for you: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/papers/deconvLevinEtalCVPR11.pdf   pay attention to 2.1.1, that's the part for blurred kernel estimation

Answer (score 1):

**First**, deconvolution methods can be used to answer 2 problems:

1. You know the PSF/IRF/blurring kernel/convolution kernel (however you call it) and you try to retrieve the Original Signal.
2. You know the Original Signal and try to recover the IRF.

The method is the same for both since their role is symmetrical in the convolution process:

```
MeasuredSignal = IRF*OriginalSignal + AdditiveNoise
```

**Second**, it looks like on line 5 of your code you want to compute

```
cv = ifft(T*IRF);
e = uint8(c)-uint8(cv);
```

otherwise you are not using your newly calculated IRF in the calculation of the error...hence the constant error values.

**Finally**, and that's where i don't know much, it seems to me that the SNR or your coefficient K should not be a constant, but vary with frequency depending on the type of noise (e.g. gaussian shape for gaussian noise). Althought if you assume white noise it would indeed be constant...